# unreachable network error when establishing a bluetooth connection between raspberrypi and laptop

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, network-programming

I have a c++ script, which I am running on my raspberry pi to automatically connect to a device that attempts connection and receives arrays of the fixed size 8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    int server_sock = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    memset(&loc_addr.rc_bdaddr, 0, sizeof(loc_addr.rc_bdaddr));
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    if (bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to bind Bluetooth socket");
        return 1;
    }
    listen(server_sock, 1);
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Waiting for connections..." << std::endl;
        int client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
        if (client_sock < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to accept connection" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "Connection accepted" << std::endl;
        while (true) {
            float buffer[8];
            int bytes_read = read(client_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            if (bytes_read > 0) {
                std::cout << "Received array of floats:" << std::endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                    std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "Connection closed or read error" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        close(client_sock);
    }
    close(server_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it, it waits with the message

```
$ ./client
Waiting for connections...
```

I then run the following python script on my laptop:

```
import struct
import bluetooth

class Driver():

    def __init__(self):
        self.serverMACAddress = 'DC:A6:32:99:B1:66' # mock mac address
        self.port = 1
        self.device_socket = None

    def main(self):
        print("connecting...")
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        self.device_socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        self.device_socket.connect((self.serverMACAddress, self.port))

    def send(self,message):
        print("sending {}".format(message))
        data = struct.pack('8f', *message)
        self.sock.send(data)
        self.sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = Driver()
    d.main()
    d.send([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8])
```

However, the python script generates the following error after 2 seconds:

```
> python .\remote_driver\driver.py
connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<Path>\remote_driver\driver.py", line 37, in <module>
    d.main()
  File "C:\<Path>\remote_driver\driver.py", line 21, in main
    self.connect()
  File "C:\<Path>\remote_driver\driver.py", line 25, in connect
    self.device_socket.connect((self.serverMACAddress, self.port))
  File "C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 96, in connect
    bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
OSError: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
```

Is there anything that I didn't consider when setting up these two scripts that is causing this error to occur? I already made my raspi discoverable with `bluetoothctl` -> `discoverable on` but it made no difference, on my windows 11 laptop, all outbound connections that do not match a rule are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Those C functions have always been dodgy. This works as a Python program on both devices as a client or a server. Windows requires Python 3.9 or later. On the Pi you might need "hciconfig hci0 piscan" first. For C code on the Pi that will connect to this Python code see:

https://github.com/petzval/btferret

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

############ CLIENT #######################

def client(node):

  node_address = "DC:A6:32:04:DB:56"
  rfcomm_channel = 16
  print("Trying to connect to " + node_address + " on channel " + str(rfcomm_channel) + "...")
  try:
    node.connect((node_address,rfcomm_channel))
  except:
    node.close()
    print("Failed. On Linux, both devices must be visible:")
    print("  hciconfig hci0 piscan")
    print("  python3 bluetooth.py")
    quit()
    
  ######### CONNECTED AS CLIENT ###########
  
  node.settimeout(3.0)    
  print("Connected OK") 
  node.send("abcd".encode())
  print("Disconnecting...")
  return
  
################# SERVER ##########
  
def server(dd):

  rfcomm_channel = 16  # change this if another program is using channel 16
  try:
    dd.bind(("00:00:00:00:00:00",rfcomm_channel))
  except:
    print("No Bluetooth, or channel " + str(rfcomm_channel) + " in use")
    print("Turn Bluetooth off/on or edit code to use a different rfcomm_channel")
    dd.close()
    quit()
  dd.listen()
  print("Waiting for remote device to connect on RFCOMM channel " + str(rfcomm_channel))
  dd.settimeout(3.0)
  flag = 0
  while flag == 0:
    flag = 1
    try:
      (node,add) = dd.accept()
    except TimeoutError:
      flag = 0
    except OSError:
      flag = 0
    except:
      dd.close()
      quit()    
 
  ####### CONNECTED AS SERVER ######### 
    
  node.settimeout(3.0)
  print("Connected OK to " + str(add))
  print("Waiting for data")
  
  dat = node.recv(4) 
  print(dat)
  print("Disconnecting...")
  node.close()            
  return
  # end server
  
  
########## START ##############


try:
  fd = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
except:
  print("No Bluetooth")
  quit()
  
print("Input s or c for this device")
print("  s = Server")
print("  c = Client")
sorc = input("? ")
if sorc[0] == 's':
  server(fd)
elif sorc[0] == 'c':
  client(fd)

fd.close()   
print("Exit")
```